# Is there a way to avoid this duplicate code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a section of code that is pretty straightforward but keep having this nagging feeling there is a simpler way to write this. Specifically the two elses;  I feel like there must be a way to avoid writing two identical else clauses in this loop.  Am I being dense?

```py
parentid = ca.get_parent_id(spacename, parentname)
if parentid is None:
    raise Exception("Unable to find parent page")

for subpage in subpages:
    ## check to see if subpage is a child of the previous page
    childreninfo = ca.get_page_children(parentid)
    if childreninfo['children']['page']['results']:
        for pageinfo in childreninfo['children']['page']['results']:
            if pageinfo['title'] == subpage:
                break
        else:
            # if we find the page somewhere in the space but it's not a child, stop! 
            info = ca.get_page_info_by_title(subpage, spacename)
            if len(info['results']) == 1:
                raise Exception("Found page but not in right location")
    else:
        # if we find the page somewhere in the space but it's not a child, stop!
        info = ca.get_page_info_by_title(subpage, spacename)
        if len(info['results']) == 1:
            raise Exception("Found page but not in right location")

    ## DO STUFF with subpage here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the outer `if:..else:` at all here. Just go straight to the `for` loop:

```
for subpage in subpages:
    ## check to see if subpage is a child of the previous page
    childreninfo = ca.get_page_children(parentid)
    for pageinfo in childreninfo['children']['page']['results']:
        if pageinfo['title'] == subpage:
            break
    else:
        # if we find the page somewhere in the space but it's not a child, stop! 
            info = ca.get_page_info_by_title(subpage, spacename)
            if len(info['results']) == 1:
                raise Exception("Found page but not in right location")
```

When looping over an empty sequence, the `else:` suite of the `for` statement is executed immediately. That's exactly the same effect as your `if ...: ... else: ...` test with code duplication.

In the event that `childreninfo['children']['page']['results']` can be a different falsey-value that can't be iterated over (such as `None`), add `or ()` in the `for` loop iterable expression to force iteration over an empty sequence:

```
for pageinfo in childreninfo['children']['page']['results'] or ():
```

Comment: Oh jeeze.  I think it's time to get more coffee.  Thank you.

Comment: Excellent. @MarcelWilson `childreninfo['children']['page'].get('results', ())` another way to handle falsey-value instead of using `or`

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal: No, that would **not** give you the same result if `childreninfo['children']['page']['results']` is set but not an iterable.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal: The code in the question works, so `childreninfo['children']['page']['result']` is *always set*. If it is not, then `.get()` may make sense, but then use `childreninfo['children']['page'].get('results') or ()` to get the same result regardless of the key being set or not, where it can be set to a falsey value such as `None` or `0` and still give the same output.

Comment: Will childreninfo['children']['page']['results'] or () work even if a non iterable is set in results key?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal: only as long as that non-iterable value [has a false boolean value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) (is *falsey*). `None` is not iterable, but considered false in boolean contexts, for example. That's also how the version in the question works, the `if` test switches to the `else:` branch only if the `'results'` value is falsey.